# How to Open a File with SUDO from within nnn File Manager

Tags: debian, file-manager, nnn

While using [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn), I need to edit a file that requires sudo privileges.

I love that I'm able to navigate quickly to the file I want to edit using nnn, and how it immediately opens the file in my editor. Yet upon making modifications, I cannot save the file without root privileges.

This really breaks the flow of what I like about nnn. Is there a quick way I can launch the editor from a file in nnn (with sudo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nnn` will use whatever editor you have defined in the environment variable `VISUAL` as the editor when editing a file by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> in the browser, or it will pick some system default editor.

This means that you may set `VISUAL` to e.g. `sudo vi` before invoking `nnn`:

```bash
VISUAL='sudo vi' nnn
```

Note that this *globally* changes the behaviour of the <kbd>e</kbd> action in the browser.

The other way to do this is to open the file using <kbd>o</kbd> from the browser.  `nnn` will then ask you what to open the file with, and you may, for example, use `sudoedit` or `sudo vi` etc.   It will then ask you whether the program you are opening uses a command line or a graphical interface. Then it will open the file in the editor appropriately.